# How to load modules on a route in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, angular-module

I want to import a module I've created in the app to be loaded on a certain route which has it's own routing within

Comment: Can you provide more explanation for the question?

Comment: Are you talking about Shared Modules? I would suggest you to go through Angular 2+ documentation once.

Comment: adding to @SagarKhatri Also look into lazy loaded modules: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Answer (score 9):

You need to have `Routes.forChild(routes)` in your custom modules' `.module.ts` file

then in your main routing load your module lazily

```
import { CustomModule } from 'your-path'
const routes: Routes = [
  { 

      path: 'your-path', loadChildren: () => CustomModule

  }
];
```

Answer (score 7):

As of **Angular 8** the new way to import child routes is this:

`{path: "user", loadChildren: () => import("./users/user.module").then(m => m.UserModule)};`

Angular team did this to be more consistent with next ES and also this will be understood by the IDEs, webpack, etc.

Answer (score 5):

What Omair said is correct, however I'm answering as well for the sake of having options.

You can also do this, if you prefer:

```js
import { CustomModule } from 'your-path'
const routes: Routes = [
  { 

      path: 'your-path', loadChildren: 'src/app/path/to/your/module/custom.module#CustomModule'
  }
];
```